# Modify the duration of a video in Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, .net, windows-media-player

for a new project, I used the Windows Media Player component. It should play a Livestream and this works fine for me, but after 10s the stream loads again and begins at 0 seconds (just like a 10s video clip).
There are two solutions I can see, but I don't know a way for them. The code itself is pretty simple.

```
        private void tbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tvplayer.currentPlaylist.name = "TV-Stream";
        tvplayer.URL = (stream-url);

    }
```

The first would be to "let the player know" that the video source is a stream and not a video, but I don't know how I should do that.

The second solution would be to modify the duration of the "video", the Media Player plays to... maybe two hours or 24 hours. I know this is somehow possible as I read about it in the Metafile Elements Reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd564668(v=vs.85).aspx), anyway, I don't see how.

Can someone give me a hint how I could do that?

I tried both HLS and HDS versions of the livestream, there is no difference. The problem is the same. The stream itself has a H.264 MP4-format.
I guess the problem is that the livestream is loaded in 10s-segments.

Comment: What kind of livestream is it? HLS?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, I was wrong. It's HDS. I am opening an F4M file. The stream itself is H.264 MP4.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all relevant info like that, as well as relevant code. Do you feed the player the manifest, or one segment?

Comment: @CodeCaster done. The stream-url doesn't matter, as the problem persists with other stream-sources I tried.